# Можно ли наследовать от одного класса поля и методы разных модификаторов доступа в C++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование

Не нашёл никакой информации об этом. Можно ли наследовать от одного класса поля и методы разных модификаторов доступа?

Например есть такой класс:

```
class ClassA
{
protected:

    int someVar;

    void fun1();

public:

    void setVar(int var);

    int getVar();

};
```

Поля и методы роли не играют. Самое главное, что есть что-то с модификатором **protected** и **public**.

И нужно во втором классе наследовать как поля и методы с модификатором **protected**, так и **public**.

```
class ClassB : protected ClassA
{
private:

    // Что-то новое в классе B

public:

    // Что-то новое в классе B

};
```

В данном случае наследуются только поля и методы с типом **protected**, но можно написать и `class ClassB : public ClassA`, тогда будут наследоваться с модификатором **public**.

Я пишу небольшой проект с графикой, а этот код написал лишь для примера, но суть он отражает.
Нужно наследовать от класса поля и методы сразу с двумя модификаторами, но если написать что-то типа `class ClassB : public ClassA, protected ClassA`, то код не скомпилируется.

Возможно ли вообще в C++ такое наследование? Нигде не нашёл информации, везде пишут только о том как наследовать с одним модификатором, либо с разными модификаторами, но от нескольких разных классов.

Comment: *В данном случае наследуются только поля и методы с типом protected, но можно написать и class ClassB : public ClassA, тогда будут наследоваться с модификатором public.* - ничего подобного...

Comment: Доступ в наследнике зависит от 1) спецификатора члена в базе; 2) спецификатора наследования. Так как вы используете protected наследование, то public и protected станут protected в наследнике. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/860353) простое объяснение.

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться? Простыми словами? Как это понимать - "*Нужно наследовать от класса поля и методы сразу с двумя модификаторами*"? Вы хотите, чтоб унаследованный член был одновременно и открытым, и закрытым?

Comment: @Mikhailo ClassB должен иметь все поля и методы ClassA _(someVar, fun1(), setVar(int var), getVar())_, но так как someVar и fun1() имеют тип _protected_, а setVar(int var) и getVar() имеют тип _public_, нельзя сразу все поля и методы наследовать. Либо мы наследуем только setVar(int var) и getVar() с помощью _class ClassB : public ClassA_, либо наследуем только someVar и fun1() с помощью _class ClassB : protected ClassA_. Мне нужно наследовать сразу все поля и методы из ClassA, но, похоже, C++ не позволяет так делать и наследовать можно в данном случае только либо public, либо только protected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все методы и поля наследуются:

```
class ClassA {
    protected:
        int someVar;
        void fun1() {
            cout << "ClassA::fun1()\n";
            }
    public:
        void setVar(int var) {
            cout << "ClassA::setVar()\n";
            someVar = var;
            }
        int getVar() {
            cout << "ClassA::getVar()\n";
            return someVar;
            }
    };

class ClassB : public ClassA {
    public:
        void someNew() {
            ClassA::fun1();
            }
    };

int main() {
    ClassB b;
    b.someNew();
    b.setVar(8);
    cout << b.getVar() << endl;
    }
```

Как видите, все работает и все вызывается. Вы не можете вызвать `ClassA::fun1()` из `main()` - но это не из-за того, что она не наследуется, а потому что `protected`, т.е. вызывается только из класса и его наследников.

Answer (score 3):

Наследуется всё. Но по-разному. По существу, модификатор наследования просто меняет доступ наследника к унаследованным членам.

Думаю, вам поможет такая табличка, в которой показано, что во что превращается.

```
                     Модификатор наследования
-------------------------------------------------------------
Модификатор члена |  public     |  protected  |  private    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
public            |  public     |  protected  |  private    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
protected         |  protected  |  protected  |  private    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
private           |  недоступен |  недоступен |  недоступен |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Так понятнее?

Answer (score 1):

> В данном случае наследуются только поля и методы с типом protected

Всегда наследуются все поля и методы.

От того, какое (`public`/`private`/`protected`) это наследование, зависит, кто будет иметь к ним доступ.